# Adding Image to Javafx Application

Tags: javafx-2

I am having problem in adding logo to my javafx desktop application. The error received is "Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found". I checked for this but there was no such mistake.

```
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.*;

public class Main extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try  {
            primaryStage.setTitle("App");
            primaryStage.setIconified(true);
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("logo.jpg"));
            AnchorPane root=new AnchorPane();
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
            Scene s=new Scene(root, 800, 600);
            primaryStage.setScene(s);
            primaryStage.show();
        } 
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"Sample.fxml"` needs to be in the same package as the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Image` has one constructor that takes a `String` argument. This argument is the *URL* of the image. `"logo.jpg"` is not a valid URL. You would have better luck using the `InputStream` variant of the constructor:

```
primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("logo.jpg")));
```

(in the case above, `logo.jpg` has to be in the same package as the class; modify the path accordingly if it isn't)